# ng-repeat highlights all links when only one visited

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, highlight

Here's the code:

```
<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="company in companies | orderBy:'name' | filter:companies_filter">
        <a href="#!/companies" ng-click="companySelected(company)">
            {{company.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The code is working, but what happens is that when I select just one company, all companies in the list gets highlighted like I visited them. Is there something I have add to this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have the same href for all companies, if you are using ui-router you can add a param to your route, for example:

```
$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'companies',
    url: '/companies/:companyId'
});
```

and you can use this way:

```
<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="company in companies | orderBy:'name' | filter:companies_filter">
        <a href="#!/companies/{{company.id}}" ng-click="companySelected(company)">
            {{company.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

By this way, every company will have its own href and this will not happen.
If it is not clear, please let me know which route lib you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you have set the same `href` but You should use `ng-style` and not ng-click like so :

```
<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="company in companies | orderBy:'name' | filter:companies_filter"  ng-class="{ active: isActive('#!/companies/'+company.id) }">
        <a href="#!/companies">
            {{company.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in your js

```
$scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
     return viewLocation === $location.path();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The href is the same for every link. You need to append something to the end of each one to make them unique. Something like:

```
<a href="#!/companies?id={{company.id}}" ng-click="companySelected(company)">
```

it doesn't matter if your code doesn't do anything with the parameter.

Comment: FYI, my answer is the easier route to follow if you're just trying to get this to work. Leonardo's answer is more correct in terms of doing this the "right way." If you go that route, you really should not need the function you are calling with ng-click at all. Your routing should handle this navigation.